# babel's language selection breaks biblatex-chicago's @online entry

Tags: biblatex, biber, babel, biblatex-chicago

In a mostly monolingual (English) document, biblatex-chicago throws a `Missing \endcsname` error on a language switch in an `online` entry (but not `misc`, `article`, `book`, `legislation`, `video` or any other I've used). This doesn't happen with vanilla biblatex.

How can I make this work? I need the language switch especially for Thai entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}
\babelprovide[import]{thai}
\babeltags{thai = thai}
\babeltags{es = spanish}

% \usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{SE:Lefurgy:When_is_it,
    author   = {Bill Lefurgy},
    title    = {When is it appropriate to use \enquote{scare quotes}?},
    organization = {Stack Exchange},
    url      = {https://english.stackexchange.com/q/69547/59745},
    date     = {2013-10-08},
    urldate  = {2022-03-06},
}

@online{SNSP::Victimas_de_Delitos,
    title    = {\textes{Víctimas de Delitos del Fuero Común 2020}},
    organization = {\textes{Secretariado Ejecutivo del Sistema Nacional de Seguridad Pública}},
    url      = {https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zoXcMNUUSChtT99FWY9LZAweqtEzIIgz/view},
    date     = {2021-08-20},
    urldate  = {2022-03-06},
}

@misc{BT::Prices_of_important,
    title    = {\textthai{ราคาสินค้าอุตสาหกรรมที่สำคัญ} \mkbibbrackets{Prices of important industial commodities}},
    organization = {Bank of Thailand},
    date     = {2022-02-28},
    url      = {https://www.bot.or.th/App/BTWS_STAT/statistics/BOTWEBSTAT.aspx?reportID=90&language=TH},
    urldate  = {2022-03-06},
}
\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=english]{csquotes}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}

\begin{document}

Good.\autocite{SE:Lefurgy:When_is_it}
Bad.\autocite{SNSP::Victimas_de_Delitos} % Doesn't work with biblatex-chicago
Good.\autocite{BT::Prices_of_important}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` uses a number of tests from the xstring package, for example

```
\IfBeginWith{\thefield{title}}{CCCCCC}
```

This is quite fragile as xstring fully expands with an `\edef` and so various commands can explode in various ways in a field subject to such a test. In your case you can avoid the error by making \textes robust:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,etoolbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babeltags{es = spanish}
\begin{document}
%\robustify\textes %avoids the error
\IfBeginWith{\textes{abc}}{CCCCCC}{yes}{no}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see what you were trying to demonstrate now. The `\IfBeginWith`, which I thought was the solution, is there precisely to produce the error, for which the commented line is the solution.